# Identity Server 4 ASP.NET Quickstart 'refused connection'

Tags: asp.net, api, identityserver4

I'm following the [Identity Server 4 Quickstart](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html#calling-the-api) and I'm having a weird issue even though I followed it step by step.

It says (translated from German) connection denied by target computer.
Whats weird about this is that in the API project "we"(I) said `ValidateAudience = false` which I thought meant that tokens aren't being validated at all.

```
// call api
var apiClient = new HttpClient();
apiClient.SetBearerToken(tokenResponse.AccessToken);

var response = await apiClient.GetAsync("https://localhost:6001/identity");
if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
}
else
{
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(JArray.Parse(content));
}
```

I am truly confused.The Client does get an accessToken so that's not the problem ... I hope.

[Github-Repo](https://github.com/CuteNickychan/I4Server)

```
Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint for /connect/token

[16:15:42 Debug] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint
Start token request.

[16:15:42 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.ClientSecretValidator
Start client validation

[16:15:42 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.BasicAuthenticationSecretParser
Start parsing Basic Authentication secret

[16:15:42 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.PostBodySecretParser
Start parsing for secret in post body

[16:15:42 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.ISecretsListParser
Parser found secret: PostBodySecretParser

[16:15:42 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.ISecretsListParser
Secret id found: client

[16:15:42 Debug] IdentityServer4.Stores.ValidatingClientStore
client configuration validation for client client succeeded.

[16:15:42 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.ISecretsListValidator
Secret validator success: HashedSharedSecretValidator

[16:15:42 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.ClientSecretValidator
Client validation success

[16:15:42 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenRequestValidator
Start token request validation

[16:15:42 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenRequestValidator
Start client credentials token request validation

[16:15:42 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenRequestValidator
client credentials token request validation success

[16:15:42 Information] IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenRequestValidator
Token request validation success, {"ClientId": "client", "ClientName": null, "GrantType": "client_credentials", "Scopes": "api1", "AuthorizationCode": null, "RefreshToken": null, "UserName": null, "AuthenticationContextReferenceClasses": null, "Tenant": null, "IdP": null, "Raw": {"grant_type": "client_credentials", "scope": "api1", "client_id": "client", "client_secret": "***REDACTED***"}, "$type": "TokenRequestValidationLog"}

[16:15:42 Debug] IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultClaimsService
Getting claims for access token for client: client

[16:15:42 Debug] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint
Token request success.
```

Comment: NOTE: it apears to be a problem with the port somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in API/Properties/lauchsettings .... when generating the project it used a default sheme and in that sheme it sets a port of 43033 or smth

Comment: I also had similar problem - IIS Express was configured on another port, so when I started the app nothing was available on port 5000/5001

Answer (score 2):

I think setting ValidateAudience = false will just ignore the audience claim, but still validate the other things in the token.

You can set the **IncludeErrorDetails** property to **true** and like this:

```
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {

            options.Audience = "payment";
            options.Authority = "https://localhost:6001/";

            //True if token validation errors should be returned to the caller.
            options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
```

When you set it to True, then you will get more details in the response header, like:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Sun, 02 Aug 2020 11:19:06 GMT
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature is invalid"
```

To further help you out, please post a sample access token and API configuration (Startup class)

See this [article](https://www.yogihosting.com/jwt-api-aspnet-core/#api-project) for further details.

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic: [Troubleshooting JwtBearer authentication problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/02/21/troubleshooting-jwtbearer-authentication-problems-in-asp-net-core/).

Comment: where exactly will they show up? also now i did include the link to the github repository

Comment: You get the WWW-Authenticate in the response from the API that receives the access token (if you use AddJwtBearer)

Comment: I fixed typo in my answer and added a link as well

Comment: hmmh for me it still just throws an error in the client.program

Comment: you dont see any response header with some clues? also you can look at the logs.

Comment: edited the question to include all that the console gave me

Comment: also the client console doesnt give anything cuz vs stops the program and throws the error

Comment: what does your API startup.cs method look like? ConfigureServices method

Comment: https://github.com/CuteNickychan/I4Server/blob/master/src/Api/Startup.cs

Comment: looks fine, you need to in the API change the scope to api1 and url to identity server. Do you see the WWW-Authenticate:response header from the API? also check in Fiddler the traffic between the client and API and see if the token is actually included. perhaps post a sample request and response in the question

Comment: whats fiddler? for test requests im using postman.also i dont set any scopes in API but i do in IdentityServer and it is set to "api1"; . . . www-authenticate:response header?

Comment: https://getfiddler.com/ is a tool to capture HTTP(S) traffic https://getfiddler.com/
Audience in the API must match the one used in the identity server.

Comment: ok so when fiddler is running the vs doesnt throw an exception anymore but the responsestatuscode is bad gateway